# Различия в настройках линкера при подключении библиотек

Tags: c, codeblocks, компоновщик

Работая с различными `C`-библиотеками, я заметил, что они несколько по-разному подключаются в плане настроек линкера. Пытался вывести общее правило, но окончательно запутался.

Например, если сравнить способы подключения `SDL` и `libxl`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я полагал, что `Search directories -> Linker` отвечает за пути поиска `lib`-файлов, поэтому должен ссылаться на папку `\lib`. Но, по-видимому, `libxl` не укладывается в это правило, потому что в его случае указан путь к `\bin`, где находится только `dll`-файл.

Помогите разобраться, за что отвечают:

1) `Search directories -> Linker`?

2) `Linker settings -> Link libraries`?

3) `Linker settings -> Other linker options`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-lSDL2` (например) в `Other linker options` означает то же самое, что `SDL2` в `Link libraries`.

В `Other linker options` можно также добавлять любые другие флажки для линковщика.

Флажок `-lSDL2` заставляет линковщик искать в путях, которые вы выбрали в `Search directories -> Linker` (а также среди библиотек, которые поставляются с компилятором), один из следующих файлов:

- `libSDL2.a`
- `SDL2.lib`
- `SDL2.dll`

`.a` - это статические библиотеки, либо тонкие обертки для динамических (`.dll`). Это "родной" формат для MinGW, и с ним обычно меньше всего проблем.

`.lib` - это статические библиотеки, собранные в Visual Stuido. С ними иногда возникают проблемы, особенно если их интерфейс - не на голом С.

`.dll` - это динамические библиотеки. Должны подключаться нормально даже без `.a`-обертки, если собраны на MinGW. Возможно будут работать, если собраны в Visual Stuido и имеют интерфейс на голом С.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @MGNeo Пожалуйста. :) Добавил еще объяснение по поводу `libxl` и `.dll`.

Answer (score 1):

Можно и так, и так.

В левой части, как правило можно указывать что-то с полным путем, и так-же оно понимает `.dll` - автоматически делает из него экспорт функций (mingw Windows).

В правой части - стандартные ключи формата -l `либнейм`, понимает только `.a` сборки и `.so` для Линукс. А так-же прочие стандартные ключи линкера, как например: `-L../src/.libs`, `-Wl,-rpath=../src/.libs`.

Подробнее про mingw и dll http://www.mingw.org/wiki/createimportlibraries , про mingw (gcc) и синтаксис подключения библиотек http://www.mingw.org/wiki/specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use

Comment: Большое спасибо за объяснение.